# MockServer with Quarkus: "Discovered multiple competing ParameterResolvers"

Tags: kotlin, junit, quarkus, mockserver

I'm trying to use [`MockServer`](https://www.mock-server.com/) to test an API Client with Quarkus. Here is my test code:

```
//@QuarkusTest
@ExtendWith(QuarkusTestExtension::class, MockServerExtension::class)
class APIClientTest(private val mockServerClient: MockServerClient) {
    @Test
    fun testClient() {
        assert(mockServerClient.hasStarted())
    }
}
```

Running this produces the following error:

> `Discovered multiple competing ParameterResolvers for parameter [org.mockserver.client.MockServerClient mockServerClient] in constructor [public com.example.APIClientTest(org.mockserver.client.MockServerClient)]: io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension@5bff6eec, org.mockserver.junit.jupiter.MockServerExtension@a2f7328`

How can I use MockServer in conjunction with Quarkus?